# When starting my Azure project in local debug mode, I get "Object reference not set to instance of an object"

Tags: c#, azure

... And then what happens is the application fails to start.  I have the cloud service set as the startup project, and the HttpFacingInterface project, an MVC application, set as the only role.  I have tried loading and unloading everything as well as deleteing the role and re-adding it in the cloud service.  I'm not sure when this started, as I had been working on a third project in the solution, a unit test project, which also exists but isnt added as a role to the cloud service.  Please help, I'd like the application to run normally.

Additional Info:

I don't get a stack trace and it doesn't break into the debugger.  It just gives me a popup and it fails to do anything else.  I'm assuming it's a config error.

At this point I'm going to start a new project and copy my code into it.  Despite finding the exact revision which broke debugging I can't get the problem to go away in the current revision.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the error?

Comment: @BrendanGreen I don't get a stack trace, nor does it break into the debugger.  I get a popup and it fails to do anything else.  I'm sort of assuming it's a config error, I just dont know what to look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately what I did was delete the cloud service and re-create it, then add in the MVC Web Project.  That fixed everything.  I have no idea which config file was messed up or how, but this solved the problem.